# How to make functions and procedures visible in intellij database source

Tags: intellij-idea

I have configured my oracle database in intellij and I already can see the tables, views ...etc (find attached screenshot).
[image]

I miss two things **procedures** and **functions** . How to make them visible?

UPDATE:
here how it looks like in sql developer:

[image]

Comment: are you sure they are available in the db? check right-click -> properties on the oracle for more options or on the scheme

Comment: In Oracle SQL Developer tool, the functions and tools are there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the `routines` node? It should be there. Note that you can navigate to a table/function via Navigate | Symbol action - just make sure that the filter in Navigate popup includes SQl files:

[image]